# Как загружать GLSL шейдеры в Java с LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

*Сап*. В *Java* я, можно сказать, новичок. Не знаю, чем это определяется, но вот у меня при написании некоей игры на Java с использованием *OpenGL* возникли проблемы, а точнее, вопросы.

Вопрос заключается в том, как загружать шейдеры из файлов, читать их, и компилировать?
В C++ всё это проходит через стандартный <`fstream`>, и в документации к OpenGL всё тоже делается через C++. Я понятия не имею, как реализовать аналог того, что написано в документации, на Java.

Буду благодарен за развёрнутый ответ, или же за ссылки на какие-либо полезные ресурсы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В Java есть специальные классы `FileReader` и `FileWriter` для чтения и записи файлов. https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/6.8.php

Comment: Для работы с файлами так же есть `java.nio.file.Files`. Вот: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html